# C# - Use a Third Parties Public Key To Encrypt Data Sent to Third Party

Tags: c#, sql, encryption, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have been given a task to encrypt data that will be stored in our database and sent to one of our customers. I figured the best way to do this is to use asymetric encryption so that once we have encrypted it with our customer's public key nobody within but the customer (owner of the private key) will be able to decrypt it.

I would like to store our customer's public key, algorithm type (RSA or DSA), and expiration date in our database instead of managing their certificate. The question is how can I store and use their public key? I have created the following little program to test and I am running into problems.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string publicKeyString = "30 81 89 02 81 81 00 c2 6e 7e e8 78 66 3d 74 fd a7 57 21 24 2d c0 ee 53 59 54 14 db f5 cb 5e 8c 64 c8 73 d5 83 d7 12 57 3f e2 92 54 9a 87 94 18 71 04 c8 b5 92 44 27 78 e9 d3 de cb 5f f6 93 75 c0 46 6b 50 c7 45 a8 38 f9 a1 83 8e 26 51 5a 8c 22 95 8e 2b 4c 10 ea c6 85 ed 02 ed 66 81 ef a3 55 15 ad 64 33 d3 bd ca 75 db 35 44 49 54 ef 6a ca 2a d5 90 a7 9b be 03 40 62 16 fd be 39 fb b6 f0 6b f8 f1 00 c0 c5 02 03 01 00 01";
        const string stringToEncrypt = "11111111111111111111";

        var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        var encryptedData = Encrypt(encoding.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt), encoding.GetBytes(publicKeyString));

        Console.WriteLine("**** Encrypted String ****");
        Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(encryptedData));

        var decryptedData = Decrypt(encryptedData);

        Console.WriteLine("**** Decrypted String ****");
        Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(decryptedData));

        Console.ReadKey();


    }

    static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] dataToEncrypt, byte[] publicKey)
    {

        var exponent = new byte[] { 1, 0, 1 };
        var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsa.ImportParameters(new RSAParameters() { Modulus = publicKey, Exponent = exponent });
        var encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false);
        return encryptedData;
    }

    static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] dataToDecrypt)
    {
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\certs\BP_DEV_CERT_1024.p12", "password");
        var rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider) cert.PrivateKey;
        var decryptedData = rsa.Decrypt(dataToDecrypt, false);
        return decryptedData;

    }

}
```

When I run this program I get "The data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 128 bytes." This leads me to believe the way I am prepare
the public key to be used is totally wrong.

So I guess I need to know a couple of things:

1. I can copy the public key from the certificate but how should I store it in the database?
2. How should I properly covert the public key string to a proper byte array?
3. Any other pointers that someone may have.

Comment: I just realized what I need to do first is convert the public key (which is a hex dump) to a byte array.

Comment: If that fixed your problem, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: It could be that you have to wait some time before you can answer your own question, but please do!

Answer (score 1):

RSA and other asymmetric algorithms are not suitable for encrypting data in bulk. The maximum message length is a few bytes less than the key modulus. Of course, you could form the data into blocks and apply RSA encryption repeatedly, but this is still horribly slow. Instead, RSA is used to exchange encryption keys for a symmetric cipher.

I recommend you use S/MIME to encrypt your customers' data. It's a standard that has been widely reviewed for security, and you probably already have a library to support the protocol. Most email clients support S/MIME, so your customers probably already have the software that they need.

S/MIME (and PGP) work by generating a key for a symmetric cipher like AES—the "content encryption key". This is used to encrypt the message. Then that symmetric key is encrypted with the public RSA key—the "key encryption key"—of each recipient. The encrypted content encryption key is sent along with the cipher text to each recipient.

Comment: I thought about that however the data is only a short string...no longer than 20 bytes.

Comment: @idflyfish The other problem you'll have is that you are converting your cipher text (which is random bytes in the 0-255 range) to a string with UTF-8; since there will be byte sequences that don't map to a character under UTF-8, the cipher text will be corrupted. Instead, use something like Base-64 or hex to produce text from your byte array.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using hex to represent the string. Works great.